# Составить двумерный вектор из одномерного

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

У меня есть вектор структур.

```
struct myStr {
    int a;
    float b;
    bool c; 
};

std::vector<myStr> vec;
```

Мне нужно составить из этого вектора двумерный вектор таким образом, чтобы получилась таблица, колонки которой - значения a, столбцы - значения b. Если нет такого элемента (с соответствующими a и b), вставляем 0.

Проблема заключается в том, что формирование такого вектора происходит очень долго, если делать все напрямую : возможных значений a - 700, b - 16.

То, что есть сейчас:
получаю 2 вектора: в первом - все возможные значения a, во втором - все возможные значения b.
Далее, прохожусь по одному из векторов и для каждого значения выполняю поиск в исходном векторе. Получаю вектор, в котором у всех элементов одинаковое значения для a или b соответственно. Так делаю для остальных значений и получаю двумерный вектор.
Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как заполнять отсутствующие значения нулями.

Код:

```
std::vector<myStr> searchForStrs(std::vector<myStr> vec, int a) const
{
    std::vector<myStr> resultVec;
    for (auto v : vec)
    {
        if(v.getA() == a)
        {
            resultVec.push_back(v);
        }
    }
    return resultVec;
}

...

for (auto a : aValues)
{
    std::vector<myStr> strsByA = searchForStrs(vec, a);
    resultVector.push_back(strsByA);
}

return resultVector;
```

Как возможно наиболее оптимально решить данную задачу?

Comment: Для поиска можно использовать сортировку вектора структур по значению `a`; затем бинарный поиск (`std::lower_bound`, `std::upper_bound`, `std::equal_range`) для поиска набора структур с заданным значением `a`.


Ещё можно сделать `std::unordered_map<int, std::list<myStr> > strsByA`, один раз пройтись по вектору структур и для каждой структуры положить в хеш таблицу по ключу `a` саму структуру (добавить в список), тогда при обходе 700 значений `a` вы по ключу сможете вытаскивать список структур с заданным значением.
И да, из условия не очень понятно что требуется.

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что `struct myStr` не нуждается селектору `getA()` и тому подобных, поскольку все данные открыты для клиента. Ну а для решения данной задачи просто легче использовать `std::map`, чем вектор.

```
myStr ms, ms1;
std::map<int, float> mymap; 
mymap[ms.a] = ms.b; 
cout << ms1.a   << '\t' << mymap[ms1.a] ; // заполнил нулем
```

ну и т.д.
Честно говоря, я не очень понел условия задачи, что надо заполнять нулями. Приведите пример входных и выходных данных, тогда я добавлю в ответ...

Comment: У меня есть вектор, например, классных руководителей в школе. 
struct Teachers {
int classNumber;
int classLetter;
std::string Name;
}
Мне нужно составить таблицу, в которой столбцами  были бы номера классов (1 - 11), а строками - буквы классов - а, б, в, г, д.
На пересечении - соответствующий классный руководитель. Если  мы не нашли в векторе классных руководителей элемента для класса 1-д, например, в эту ячейку ставим 0.

Answer (score 0):

Создаёте двумерный вектор фиксированного размера (`n` строк и `m` столбцов, где `n` - количество различных значений поля `a` (в вопросе 700), `m` - количество различных значений `b` (в вопросе - 16) ), где каждой i-ой строке соответствует i-ое значение `a`, а j-тому столбцу - j-ое значение `b`. Заполните этот вектор нулями.

Потом пройдитесь по вектору структур и поставьте соответствующее значение в двумерный вектор (`v[aIndex(s.a)][bIndex(s.b)] = someIntFlag`).

А чтобы для очередного значения `a` вычислить соответсвующую ему строку в двумерном векторе, заведите словарь `std::unordered_map<int,int> indexOfA`,
пройдитесь по всем значениям `a` (700 в вопросе), и для каждого значения положите в словарь по ключу `значение a` индекс - номер строки: `indexOfA[aValue] = rowIndex;`. И тогда функция aIndex  будет выглядить как

```
int aIndex(int a){
    return indexOfA[a];
}
```

Только нужно быть уверенным что для всех значений из вектора структур есть соответсвующая запись в словаре (то есть что 700 значений `a` точно покрывают все возможные значения в векторе структур поля `a`)

Насчёт `float b` возможно не подойдёт вариант с получением индекса из словаря, потому что сравнивать вещественные числа напрямую нельзя, но так как их всего 16, то можно для значения поля b очередной структуры пройтись по всем возможным 16 значениям, сравнить с некоторой погрешностью и получить индекс требуемого столбца.

А вообще, заводить целый двумерный вектор, в котором большая часть значений будет нулевой не есть хорошо, можно использовать разреженные матрицы на списках (либо вручную реализовать, либо использовать библиотеки).